How to handle Facebook OAuth2 with 2FA
I'm creating an automation flow with puppeteer to log in to Facebook and get the User Access Token. The code is a NodeJS code and pretty simple for now:
require("dotenv").config();
const { tagmanager } = require("googleapis/build/src/apis/tagmanager");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  // Lança o navegador com a UI visível para que possamos acompanhar o processo
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Define a URL para o fluxo de login do Facebook
  const facebookLoginURL = `https://www.facebook.com/v16.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=${process.env.FB_APP_ID}&redirect_uri=${process.env.FB_REDIRECT_URI}&scope=email,public_profile&response_type=code`;

  // Vai para a página de login do Facebook
  await page.goto(facebookLoginURL);

  // Espera o span com o texto específico "Permitir todos os cookies"
  await page.waitForFunction(() => {
    const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("span"));

    // Verifica se algum elemento contém o texto "Permitir todos os cookies"
    const targetElement = elements.find(
      (element) => element.textContent.trim() === "Permitir todos os cookies"
    );

    // Se o elemento for encontrado, retorna true para sair do loop
    if (targetElement) {
      return true;
    }

    // Continua o loop se não encontrar o elemento
    return false;
  });

  // Encontra e clica diretamente com page.click()
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("span"));

    // Verifica se algum elemento contém o texto "Permitir todos os cookies"
    const targetElement = elements.find(
      (element) => element.textContent.trim() === "Permitir todos os cookies"
    );

    if (targetElement) {
      targetElement.setAttribute("id", "cookie-button"); // Atribui um ID temporário para garantir o seletor
    }
  });

  await page.click("#cookie-button"); // Usa o seletor id para clicar diretamente

  // Espera que o campo de email esteja disponível e preenche com o seu usuário de teste
  await page.waitForSelector("#email");
  await page.type("#email", process.env.FB_TEST_USER_EMAIL);

  // Preenche a senha com a senha do usuário de teste
  await page.type("#pass", process.env.FB_TEST_USER_PASSWORD);

  // Clica no botão de login
  await page.click('button[name="login"]');

  // Espera o redirecionamento para a URL de callback
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  // Obtém a URL atual (que deve conter o código de autenticação)
  const redirectedUrl = page.url();
  console.log("Redirected URL:", redirectedUrl);

  //here we need to handle 2FA
  //...

  // Extraia o código da URL de redirecionamento
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(redirectedUrl.split("?")[1]);
  const authCode = urlParams.get("code");

  console.log(`Auth Code: ${authCode}`);

  await browser.close();
})();

The puppeter code above comprises the following steps:

Open Facebook login page (OK)

Log in with user and password (OK)

Enter 2FA code (not OK)

Get User Access Token (not OK because of 3)


I'm having trouble with step 3, because I don't know how to get the code automatically, i.e. without having to enter it manually. Any solutions?
2FA is enabled in Meta Business Manager and I normally receive this code by SMS or via the Microsoft Authenticator app. I could perhaps disable 2FA for the user in question in the Meta Business Manager, but that's something I wouldn't want to do, as it reduces credibility on the Meta side, which could block the user.
So I'd like to "hear" from you about possible ways of dealing with this. Thanks in advance!
I want to handle with 2FA by using puppeteer to login on Facebook with a normal user account.

Your waitForNavigation() has a race condition. Use page.$$eval rather than evaluate() with a querySelectorAll as the first line. As for the main question, you'll need to automate your MFA somehow (check your email inbox or text messages programmatically, or use an authenticator device that issues the 6-digit code programmatically), or type it in manually and save the session to avoid having to do it often.

Twilio: Receive SMS

@ggorlen, I've tried it with Twilio. It seems it can just work in the paid version. With the trial version I couldn't so far recieve SMS from Facebook.

Glad it worked out with the paid version. Feel free to post a self answer with your solution to help others with the same problem as you.

@ggorlen, sorry, I wanted to say: It seems it can work with the paid version, but I didn't tried it (I mean I didn't buy a paid service for it neither test it). That means, with the trial version it's sure it's not possible. With the payed version, we need to test.
